# Mock MembershipProvider with custom methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I'm working on.  I'm using a custom MembershipProvider (MyCustomMembershipProvider) to access membership information because we already have a database with our own schema that I need to use.

I am using classes similar to the NerdDinner 2 example where I have an AccountMembershipService (implementing an IMembershipService) that contains a MembershipProvider so I can inject a different mock provider.  However, I have extended the MyCustomMembershipProvider with a few different methods for CreateUser and ChangePassword.  These methods are not available in the MembershipProvider unless you know it's a custom one.

Am I going about this incorrectly? Do I need another layer that is an interface that includes my new provider methods?

Comment: I'm new to MVC and mock testing so I'm probably not explaining the situation very well.  I have an AccountMembershipService that takes a MembershipProvider as an argument in the constructor.  This way, when I'm running the application, the MembershipProvider that is passed in is a MyCustomMembershipProvider...and when I'm testing, the MembershipProvider passed in is a MockMembershipProvider.  So, when I call CreateUser on the AccountMembershipService, the CreateUser is not available on the MembershipProvider that the AccountMembershipServices contains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure I understand what your problem is.  If you're using a wrapper interface over the MembershipProvider, then it shouldn't matter what methods the provider implements because your app is only using the interface, and you can change the interface to whatever you want.

Or are you asking how you would call your custom methods from your Custom provider?  If so, then the whole bit about mocking and what not are just red herrings, because it has nothing to do with the problem.

If that is indeed your problem, then you would simply cast the Membership.Provider method to the type of your provider.  Something like this:

```
var myProvider = Membership.Provider as MyCustomerMembershipProvider;
myProvider.CreateUser(...);
```